# SQL Server: How to select 4001 character property from JSON

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

I have a SQL table that contains an nvarchar(max) column that is being used for JSON data. One of the JSON properties is *the string version* of another JSON object. This inner JSON literally contains escaped quotes, etc. Example:

```
{
  "id": 55,
  "innerJson": "{\"innerId\": 199}"
}
```

The inner JSON is about 10,000 characters long, give or take a couple thousand.

I would like to be able to select this inner JSON in SQL server, however, I seem to be running up against the 4000 character limit. It's too long to use JSON_VALUE() and too simple to use JSON_QUERY(), which is extremely frustrating.

[MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql) "If you have to return scalar values greater than 4000 characters, use OPENJSON", but doesn't really describe how.

I HAVE found a way to select it, but it involves nested OPENJSON() calls:

```
select *
from OPENJSON((
    select [value]
    from OPENJSON((
        select JsonColumn
        from table
        where Id = 55
    ))
    where [key] = 'innerJson'
))
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
select *
from OPENJSON((
    select JsonColumn
    from table
    where Id = 55
), '$.innerJson')
```

So, my questions:

1. Is there a way to select > 4000 character strings?
2. Is there a cleaner way to select the "innerJson" without using nested OPENJSON calls? Do I have to nest it because it's a string, not an object?
3. Why doesn't the 2nd query work? Is it because I'm running up against that 4000 character limit?

Thanks!